# Customize Keyboard Volume Slider in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, button-remapping

My keyboard (the Das Keyboard 4 Professional) has a big red volume dial. At work this is completely useless to me, as I have no speakers, nor do I need to hear any sounds.

Is there some way I can make it do something else? Maybe a scroll wheel? I don't mind completely disabling the sound shortcuts if need be (remapping them to something else perhaps).